# Access script arguments from within script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that I can run like this: `bash myscript.sh -ram 4096M -jar something.jar -dir /home/something` I would like to be able to access the variable `ram`, `jar`, and `dir` from within the script. How do I do this?

Comment: I see now, see the above dupe and read about `getopts`.

Comment: Heres an example http://pastebin.com/uZ5MHQT9 Can you please edit it so it will work?

Comment: see also `$1` `$2`…, and `shift`. Though the method in the linked answer is better.

Comment: The "Duplicate" dosen't make any sense. Please make a very simple example, of my pastebin

Comment: @user3524823: Is there some reason why you want to use this syntax? It’s traditional for multi-character options to be preceded by a double dash (`--`), e.g., `myscript.sh --ram 4096M --jar something.jar --dir /home/something`.

Comment: @everybody: This is not a duplicate of the marked question. That question deals with single-character options (e.g., `-a`, `-b`, `-c`, `-e`, `-i`, and `-v`), and is answered by “use `getopts`”. *This* question is about multi-character options (e.g., `--ignore-case`, `--invert-match`, `--ram`, `--jar`, and `--dir`). Can you parse ***those*** with `getopts`?

Comment: I don't care if its -- or - . That dosen't matter, but I found a solution which is fine. $1,$2,$3 However I would preffer to specify --ram before the string

Comment: Do you know the answer @Scott?

Comment: I don’t know of a magic bullet – something “easy” like `getopts` – but it’s not hard to write ***an*** answer.